# Passing DOMDocument between PHP and JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, object, post, communication

The problem is about communicating an object between PHP and JQuery.

Performing `$.post` in JQuery, i want to retrieve a `DOMDocument` object generated in 'get_domdoc.php' and then be able to `$.post` it back to other PHP files, like:

```
    $.post("get_domdoc.php", {url: url}, function( domdoc )
    {

    //prepare 'domdoc' to $.post it - in a usable format - to another PHP file

    });
```

Is this possible? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Does it have to be posted? If the PHP files are to run in the same session, it would be more practical to retrieve the DOM HTML or XML, and store that as a string in `$_SESSION` to reconstitute as a DOMDocument object on the next PHP page (unless the HTML or XML is very large)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way is probably [turning it into a string in the sending PHP script](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php), treating it as string data in jQuery, and creating a new `DOMDocument` in the receiving PHP script.

You may theoretically be able to `serialize()` the DOMDocument object, but that feels kludgy (if it's possible at all). Exchanging proper XML looks like the way to go IMO.

Comment: I don't know what i was thinking, really. Using first $str = $domdoc->saveHTML() and then using DOMDocument::LoadHTML($str) makes it very easy. Thank you!